# unable to start ride.py

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

i am very new in this topic. i want to learn more about automation. so i came across the robotframework during my search. the installation of the robotframework worked but when i want to start "ride.py" it gives me this output. am i right that the command "ride.py" should open an IDE where i can start scripting? But i just get this output. Can ya please help me what i did wrong.

i use the OS Ubuntu on a VM

```
w@w-Virtual-Machine:~$ ride.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/w/.local/bin/ride.py", line 21, in <module>
    from robotide import main
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from robotide.utils import PY2, PY3
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/utils/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import robotide.lib.robot.utils
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from robotide.lib.robot.rebot import rebot, rebot_cli
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/rebot.py", line 40, in <module>
    from robotide.lib.robot.conf import RebotSettings
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/conf/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .settings import RobotSettings, RebotSettings
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/conf/settings.py", line 22, in <module>
    from robotide.lib.robot.output import LOGGER, loggerhelper
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/output/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .output import Output
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/output/output.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import pyloggingconf
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/output/pyloggingconf.py", line 19, in <module>
    from robotide.lib.robot.utils import get_error_details, unic
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/utils/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .argumentparser import ArgumentParser, cmdline2list
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/utils/argumentparser.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .misc import plural_or_not
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/utils/misc.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .robottypes import is_integer
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/utils/robottypes.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .robottypes3 import (is_bytes, is_dict_like, is_integer, is_list_like,
  File "/home/w/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/utils/robottypes3.py", line 16, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, UserString
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you installed RIDE, and I am even surprised it was installed if from `PyPi`.

Only on today's date (24-june-2022), a development version was updated to run on Python 3.10 (maybe). You can try to install, this one, but be aware of its new bugs.

I can install with:

```
pip install -U https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/archive/master.zip
```

You should browse the RIDE project page [here](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE), and look at README, CHANGELOG and Issues. Also see the Slack and Forum links.